# how to concatenate a long git command, with string from file?

Tags: bash, git

I want to do a git search for keyword across several files.
the file list will be provided from another file($3 or "${filesStr[@]}").

bellow is gsearch.sh

```
filesStr=($(< $3))
git log --binary \
    --ignore-all-space \
    --ignore-blank-lines \
    --ignore-cr-at-eol \
    --ignore-space-at-eol \   
    --ignore-space-change \
    -p -G $1 -- "${filesStr[@]}" > "$2"
```

I would run it in this way:

```
./gsearch.sh GitSearch ~/loadrc/gitsearch.findresult ~/loadrc/gitsearch.findresult.tmp
```

~/loadrc/gitsearch.findresult.tmp

```
vimrc/.vim/plugin/keymap.vim
vimrc/.vim/plugin/common.vim
```

But I got nothing in `~/loadrc/gitsearch.findresult`

if I add `echo` to `gsearch.sh` like this:

```
filesStr=($(< $3))
echo git log --binary \
         --ignore-all-space \
         --ignore-blank-lines \
         --ignore-cr-at-eol \
         --ignore-space-at-eol \
         --ignore-space-change \
         -p -G $1 -- "${filesStr[@]}" > "$2"
```

then `~/loadrc/gitsearch.findresult`

```
git log --binary \
    --ignore-all-space \
    --ignore-blank-lines \
    --ignore-cr-at-eol \
    --ignore-space-at-eol \
    --ignore-space-change \
    -p -G GitSearch -- \
    vimrc/.vim/plugin/keymap.vim \
    vimrc/.vim/plugin/common.vim
```

and manually run this command:

```
git log --binary \
    --ignore-all-space \
    --ignore-blank-lines \
    --ignore-cr-at-eol \
    --ignore-space-at-eol \
    --ignore-space-change \
    -p -G GitSearch -- \
    vimrc/.vim/plugin/keymap.vim \
    vimrc/.vim/plugin/common.vim
```

it works, I get search result from git.

Comment: Does `xargs git log --binary --ignore-all-space --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-cr-at-eol --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-space-change -p -G "$1" -- <"$3" >"$2"` do what you want?

Comment: sorry, the following is not working, I got empty result
````
xargs git log --binary --ignore-all-space --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-cr-at-eol --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-space-change -p -G "$1" -- <"$3" >"$2"
````

Comment: The concatenation part of your script works fine when I try it on my linux bash.  I added `#!/bin/bash` in gsearch.sh, first line.  I can't test the `git` portion...